# Mac's Finder shows no "Paste Item" option when pasting to a OneDrive folder

Tags: macos, finder, onedrive

On a mac Mini M1, Monterey 12.3.1 I have an issue with cutting and pasting files. I'm used to using the finders "Copy" and "Paste Item" functions. But after copying a file, when trying to paste the file on a OneDrive folder the finder shows no "Paste Item" option. And, consequently, I cannot paste the file.

Click, holding down the mouse, and moving the file works fine. Also the other way around, so copying from a OneDrive towards another folder (not Onedrive) works.

Has anybody ever seen this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.

It is an issue with multiple Office365 accounts. You need to be logged in into the OneDrive target Office365 Account, so where you are pasting to...

I have multiple O365 accounts and then this issue appears. Logging out from one account and logging into the target account solved the issue. The "Paste item" option reappeared.